# Create image on top of another uiimage

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, cgcontext

I am not able to draw image on top of another image. Below if the code I am using:

```
-(void)createImage
{

// create a new bitmap image context at the device resolution (retina/non-retina)
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imgVw_noHair_.frame.size, YES, 0.0);

// get context
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

// push context to make it current
// (need to do this manually because we are not drawing in a UIView)
UIGraphicsPushContext(context);

// drawing code comes here- look at CGContext reference
// for available operations
// this example draws the inputImage into the context
[eraser drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(50, 50)];

// pop context
UIGraphicsPopContext();

UIImage _image_ = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

}
```

The image which I get from the current context is a black image.  I want to draw eraser image on the image which I get from the context.

Comment: why do you want to draw it, you can have imageview right..!!

Comment: you just check out this answer..http://stackoverflow.com/a/1480838/1865424

Comment: @Stark - when I draw image using the same code instead of circle, warning comes and nothing gets displayed. 
`CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0`

Answer (score 4):

This is updated code which is working in my side.

```
-(void)createImage
{

   //Create context in which you have to draw
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imgvwImage.image.size, YES, 0.0);

    // get context
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // push context to make it current
    // (need to do this manually because we are not drawing in a UIView)
    UIGraphicsPushContext(context);

    //draw the old image in that context
    [imgvwImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];

    UIImage *img=[UIImage imageNamed:@"img.png"];

    //Draw your image in that context
    [img drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(50, 50)];

    // pop context
    UIGraphicsPopContext();



     UIImage *image_ = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    //Get that image
    imgvwImage.image=image_;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to draw your eraser image in rect instead of AtPoint

```
[eraser drawInRect:CGRectMake(50, 50, width, height)];
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to draw the bottom image into the context, hence you are drawing your `eraser` image on top of an uninitialized (black) background. You need to add some code to first draw your desired background image.

Comment: How can I draw desired background image?

Comment: There are several ways. For one example see the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437883/how-do-i-create-a-new-image-by-drawing-on-top-of-an-existing-one-using-quartz/1480838#1480838 and copy the 4 lines below the comment //draw original image